# How to fix "More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'"?

Tags: java, android, xml, gradle, google-translate

I am trying to use Google Cloud Translation API in my app, but when I add:

```
implementation platform('com.google.cloud:libraries-bom:20.5.0')
implementation 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-translate'
```

This error happens:

> More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'.

Adding this does not solve the issue:

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    exclude("META-INF/*.kotlin_module") 
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'` to the list?

Comment: Try adding `exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'` and `exclude 'META-INF/index.LIST'`

Comment: use `implementation platform('com.google.cloud:libraries-bom:20.2.0')`

Comment: `exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'` solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

You should add to application `build.gradle` your `packagingOptions`:

```
packagingOptions {
exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'

}
```